# TypeScript compiler: save compiled file into the same directory as source file

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I would like to compile TypeScript file (ts) to JavaScript (js) and map (js.map) files into the same directory as the source file.

I already try this in my tsconfig.json file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "outDir": "./",
   }
}
```

or

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "outDir": ".",
   }
}
```

But nothing happened. What is the correct config for that ?
Is there a `--outDir` parameters options to compile in the same directory ?

In PhpStorm, can I use a variable options perhaps in my config compiler TypeScript ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `outDir` setting to output the compiled `.js` and `.js.map` next to the Typescript files.

Try this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
   }
}
```